# AOP Advice around RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

How can I create a Pointcut around my methods annotated with @RequestMapping?

I have a Pointcut defined that I'd like to restrict a bit further:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * company.controllers.AbstractController+.*(..))")
public void methodPointcut() { }
```

Is it possible to further restrict that to only methods which are annotated with @RequestMapping?

I tried adding && @annotation to the end of the Pointcut, but that is not a well formed Pointcut.

Comment: can't you use HandlerIntercepetor?

Comment: It is, but I think the AOP approach will provide a cleaner solution down the line when requirements change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was easiest to do with two Pointcuts.

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * company.controllers.AbstractController+.*(..))")
public void methodPointcut() {}
```

and

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *)")
public void requestMapping() {}
```

Then simply doing:

@Before("methodPointcut() && requestMapping()")

Comment: RonU's answer also works, however I'm guessing it's best practice to limit the scope of PointCuts as much as possible.  Is there guidance on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify annotations in a pointcut:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@RequestMapping public * company.controllers.AbstractController+.*(..))")
public void methodPointcut() { }
```

Is this something you've already tried?

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work.  However once I fully qualified the RequestMapping annotation it did work.